# Mapping a Java program to an Operating System process

Tags: java, compiler-construction, process, operating-system, callstack

I am wondering how this happens: how is a Java program mapped to an OS process (like the one shown for Linux below):
[image: borrowed from: linuxjournal.com]

In C, it's a straightforward association in how a program is written and how the whole call stack proceeds in the OS. I was wondering how is the mapping achieved in Java? Does a method meth(), called on an object: obj, just translate to locating the address of obj.meth() & from then on stack is used the way it is in C?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'd also be curious to know the model that other OOP languages use in general (C++, Python etc).

Comment: Note that even for C the given picture is already a serious simplification. For example there's not necessarily only one heap (having one heap is quite a bad idea if you have lots of threads that want to allocate memory), then there's the thread specific data and so on. The devil's in the details and if you think about how complicated even the simple C runtime gets, just imagine how the JVM looks like :)

Comment: Of course, I just wanted to discuss a simple case of a single thread process :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a pretty complex problem. Here is a pretty good [article](http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/01/the-java-memory-architecture-1-act/) about this topic. In short, Java got two execution modes which hugely affects memory layout.

1. Some code is executed by intepreter
2. Some code are compiled to native code for better performance.

See this wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation.

And JVM got more type of memory region, like perm-gen, memory for JIT, etc.

This is well-discussed in other threads:

1. [java and memory layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714674/java-and-memory-layout)
2. [jdk1.6 memory layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896729/jdk1-6-memory-layout)

Comment: Well I wouldn't say it is "well-discussed" in those other two threads. But then memory layout of the JVM is extremely complex as you say, which means a) not many people can seriously answer this question (I couldn't; I know what memory spaces exist and what they basically do, but layout or other details? bite me) and b) even if someone wanted to it would be a pretty unwieldy post. Not sure if it's a good fit for SO.

Answer (score 1):

Most Java JVMs are plain C programs. So the picture will be the same write up to the first class file being interpreted/executed.

After that it depends on the JVM implementation. Typically they would use the stack storage  to keep track of control type information such as which classes are loaded, which threads are running etc. For the actual "program" storage the interpreter and garbage collector will use plain "malloc"/"mfree" to allocatate and free memory plus some fairly complex control structures to enable the garbage collector to function.